# Python - Display one line for each unique word

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a python code that counts the frequency of each word in a text file. The code should display one line per unique word. The code I wrote is displaying duplicate words.

```
import string

text = open('mary.txt','r')
textr = text.read()

for punc in string.punctuation:
    textr = textr.replace(punc, "")

wordlist = textr.split()

for word in wordlist:
    count = wordlist.count(word)
    print word,':',count
```

My current output is...

```
are : 1
around : 1
as : 1
at : 2
at : 2
away : 1
back : 1
be : 2
be : 2
because : 1
below : 1
between : 1
both : 1
but : 1
by : 2
by : 2
```

The output should only display `at : 2`,`be : 2`, and `by : 2` once. What should I change in my code for that to happen?

Comment: Use a dict or a set. The dict makes more sense here, but rewriting your code for a set would be less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're creating a list of all the words and then looping over them. You want to create some sort of data structure that only stores unique words. A `dict` is a good way to do this, but it turns out there's a specialized collection in Python called a `Counter` that's built for exactly this purpose.

Give this a try (untested):

```
from collections import Counter
import string

text = open('mary.txt','r')
textr = text.read()

for punc in string.punctuation:
    textr = textr.replace(punc, "")

counts = Counter(textr.split())

for word, count in counts.items():
    print word,':',count
```

Comment: I get the error message `for word, count in counts:
ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: @AyZhng Sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

As another way to implement this, you could have taken your solution, added all of the entries as (word, count) tuples to a set, then printed the set. You should probably rethink your implementation anyway like @smarx points out but this will fix the issue using your native code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import string

frequency = {}
text = open('mary.txt','r')
textr = text.read()

for punc in string.punctuation:
    textr = textr.replace(punc, "")

wordlist = textr.split()

for word in wordlist:
    count = frequency.get(word,0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for words in frequency_list:
    print words,':', frequency[words]
```